# Typical Applications of Linear System Solver in Game Developemnt

Tags: mathematics, linear-algebra, numerical-methods

I am going to write a custom solver for linear system.

I would like to survey the typical problems involved the linear system solving in games. So that I can custom optimization on these problems based on the shape of the matrix.

currently I am focus on these problems:

- B-Spline editing (I use a linear solve to resolve the C0, C1, C2 continuity)
- Constraint in Simulation (especially Position-Constraint, cloth)

Both of them are Banded Matrix.

I want to hear about some other applications of a linear system in games.

Thank you.